Confused with matlab arbitrary precision toolboxes
I have a recursive computation code of mine (containing only simple +, *, exp, etc arithmetic on complex valuated numbers) that starts to loose precision when increasing the depth of iterations and I was willing to see if using quadruple-precision (or higher) numbers would help.
For this I was willing to try following toolboxes:

HPF
MPT

But I'm a bit confused about how to use them because precision is to be provided as a number of digits after comma and I don't see from examples how this relates to quantities being stored/manipulated as 64/128 bits values.
Can you show me some quick example to create quadruple-precision (i.e. 128 bits) with those toolboxes and explain relation with precision as number of digits as expected as argument in those toolboxes ?

Just to be clear, those are user-contributed tools, not from MATLAB.  You should probably ask the authors.

Have you considered using the symbolic data type and vpa? Computation will be slower, but you get arbitrary precision

Thanks @LuisMendo and AnderBiguri  I don't have symbolic toolbox license and finally used Mutiprecision Computing Toolbox do to the test (NB: It is no free after trial but extremely fast and solve my precision issue in recurrence). Regarding link digits/bits correspondance, looking at how floating points encoding the relation is digits = (bits - bitsReserverExponent)*log10(2) , so almost 34 digits for quadrule-precision (128bits)
